# Spring swagger2: how to set HTTPS protocol?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, swagger

When I execute my spring app in swagger, the default protocol is http, and i want execute it in https, because the application runs in HTTPS. How Can I configure this?

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(metaData())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.adp.mnc.metadata.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.protocols(Sets.newHashSet("http", "https"))`

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'protocols' in 'ApiSelectorBuilder'

Comment: @Anna María Barrera Quintanilla - see full code with varman solution:

Answer (score 0):

Full code with @varman solution:

```
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            // https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1139
            .ignoredParameterTypes(AuthenticationPrincipal.class)
            .host("javaops-demo.ru")
            .protocols(Set.of("https"))
            .select()
            .paths(ant("/rest/**"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                    .title("REST API documentation")
                    .description("""
                            Application (<a href='https://javaops.ru/view/topjava'>TopJava</a>)
                            <p><b>Test credential:</b><br>
                            - user@yandex.ru / password<br>
                            - admin@gmail.com / admin<br>
                            - guest@gmail.com / guest</p>
                            """)
                    .version("1.0")
                    .build())
            .securitySchemes(List.of(new BasicAuth("basicAuth")));
  }
}
```